# Type of ternary operator integer expression when used in aggregate struct initialisation

Tags: c++, struct, conditional-operator, aggregate-initialization

I've run into an interesting warning (with GCC and clang `-Wnarrowing` at least, haven't tested other compilers), when aggregate initialising a struct using a ternary operator expression (see below code). I don't understand why the type of the expression is apparently considered `int` in the aggregate initialisation case, but is silently coerced to be a `size_t` in the others. If C++23 `size_t` literals were a thing this would not be a problem obviously, as you'd just use the correct literal type. I'm just curious what's actually going on here, if anyone knows?

```
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    struct S { size_t m; };

    S s1 = {0}; // No warning

    bool b = true;
    S s2 = {b ? 1 : 0}; // warning: narrowing conversion of '(b ? 1 : 0)' from 'int' to 'size_t'
    //S s2 = {b ? 1u : 0u}; // No warning

    size_t s3 = b ? 1 : 0; // No warning

    return s1.m || s2.m || s3;
}
```

Comment: Try `S s1 = {-1};`  and also if you make `const bool b = true;` then the warning goes.

Comment: `error: constant expression evaluates to -1 which cannot be narrowed to type 'size_t'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `b ? 1 : 0` is certainly `int`.

Brace-initialization (including aggregate initialization) is not allowed to perform *narrowing conversions*, such as a conversion from a signed type to an unsigned type. This is a narrowing conversion because some values in the source type (*i.e.*, negative numbers) cannot be represented in the destination type. When a narrowing conversion occurs in a non-brace context, it is allowed.

GCC treats the disallowed narrowing conversions as a warning instead of an error, but technically, your code is ill-formed.

Comment: Ah right, OK. I was not aware narrowing was forbidden in that context. Thanks!

Comment: From cppreference: "If the initializer clause is an expression, implicit conversions are allowed as per copy-initialization, except, for list-initialization form, narrowing conversions are prohibited (since C++11)."

Comment: Re: “ technically, your code is ill-formed” — to be completely clear, when code is ill-formed, the standard requires (slightly oversimplified) that the compiler issue a diagnostic. It does not require that the compiler refuse to compile the code. Issuing a warning is sufficient.